# Count the no. of times a word can be created using the given input string

Tags: java, java-8

I want to print the no of times the word 'hello' can be printed from the given input of characters. Can you suggest what I am doing wrong, since This code is not passing all the test cases.

```
String strInput  = br.readLine();//read the string 
    int count = 0;
    int h = 0,e = 0,l= 0,o = 0;

for (int i=0;i< strInput.length();i++){
    if(strInput.charAt(i)=='h'){
        h++;}else if(strInput.charAt(i)=='l'){
        l++;}else if(strInput.charAt(i)=='e'){
        e++;}else if(strInput.charAt(i)=='o'){
        o++;}
}

if(h>=1&&e>=1&&l>=2&&o>=1){
    count++;
    h--;
    e--;
    o--;
    l=l-2;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

also how can I refactor this piece of code?

Comment: Trivially this will fail for the input: HHEELLO. This is because the number of combinations/permutations (hint: useful search terms) is not merely the sum of counts of each character. For example, with the HHEELLO input, HELLO can be formed starting with any of - H1E1, H2E1, H1E2, H2E2 - and all of these must be counted.

Comment: could you please reformat your code, especially the `if - else if` construct, in a way that it is easily readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks almost fine; but its major problem is: it is very low-level, and therefore hard to read.

You see, all those counters and array accesses ... not so nice. And: you very much hardcoded "hello" into your code. What if you assignment will be to make this check for some arbitrary word?

So, lets give you some insights how you could improve your code.

You can use a `Map<Character, Integer>` to remember the characters you need to print one specific word:

```
String wordToCount = "hello"; // or maybe: coming form the user!
Map<Character, Integer> numberOfRequiredCharsPerChar = new HashMap<>();

for (char charToCount : wordToCount.toCharArray()) {
  if (!numberOfRequiredCharsPerChar.containsKey(charToCount)) {
    // unknown char, so we need a counter for it
    numberOfRequiredCharsPerChar.put(charToCount, new Integer(0));
  }
  int currentCounter = numberOfRequiredCharsPerChar.get(charToCount);
  numberOfRequiredCharsPerChar.put(charToCount, currentCounter+1);
}
```

So: the above iterates the "first" input, and afterwards, like for "hello", that Map tells you what you need to print it:

h x 1, e x 1, ll x 2, o x 1.

Then, in the second step, we use **copies** of that map in the reverse way:

```
int possibleCounts = 0;
String inputToCountOn = ....

Map<Character, Integer> numberOfUsedCharacters= new HashMap<>(numberOfRequiredCharsPerChar);

for (char availableChar : inputToCountOn()) {
  if (numberOfUsedCharacters.containsKey(availableChar)) {
    int currentCounter = numberOfUsedCharacters.get(availableChar);
    currentCounter--;
    if (currentCounter == 0) {
      numberOfUsedCharacters.remove(availableChar);
    } else {
      numberOfUsedCharacters.put(availableChar, currentCounter);
    }
    if (umberOfUsedCharacters.isEmpty()) {
      // that means: we fetched ALL chars we need to print the word ONCE
      possibleCounts++;
      // and reset our "counter" map
      numberOfUsedCharacters= new HashMap<>(numberOfRequiredCharsPerChar);
   }
}
... now you just print possibleCounts ...
```

Sure, this looks more complicated than your input; but it is much more flexible. And if one would spent some time to create little helper methods for each of the activities, you could write down the whole thing in a very readable way.

Comment: You need tpo change `numberOfUsedCharacters.contains`  to `numberOfUsedCharacters.containsValue`  and `currentCounter++` to `++currentCounter`. 
I was thinking about a similar generic solution using Map<Character, Integer> while checking recursively if needed chars are available.

Comment: GM. Sorry, it shoud be `containsKey` (`contains` does not compile)

Comment: Thanks. Fixed all of that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. A few comments about it:

I used GhostCat's method to map the number of occurrences of each character in the input. 

I check recursively if the characters needed are available in the input.

If so I **remove** those characters from input string, and check again. 

The solution is case sensitive.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    static String word = "hello";
    static String strInput;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        strInput  = "hoe4olelltohlemllhlhoslelo";//read the string

        Map<Character, Integer> charMap = mapNumOfChars();
        int count = 0;
        boolean done= false;
        while(!done) {

            for(Character c : charMap.keySet()) {

                if(! hasTheNeededNumOfChars(c, charMap.get(c), 0)) {

                    done= true;
                }
            }

            if(!done ) {

                //remove from input string all chars that have been "used"
                removeAllCharsUsed();
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }

    /**
     *Recursively search for num occurrences of c.
     *@param c
     *  char to search
     *@param num
     *  number of char occurrences
     *@param startFrom
     *  start searching from index
     *@return
     */
    private static boolean hasTheNeededNumOfChars(char c, int num, int startFrom) {

        int charIndex = strInput.indexOf(c, startFrom);

        //no occurances of char found
        if (charIndex < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        //if char found is last, or only one char occurrence needed
        //no need to continue checking
        if((charIndex == (strInput.length() -1)) || (num == 1) ) {

            return true;

        }else {

            //look for the remaining number of occurrences num-1
            //starting from index charIndex
            return hasTheNeededNumOfChars(c,num-1, charIndex+1);
        }
    }

    private static void removeAllCharsUsed() {

        for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {

            strInput = strInput.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(c),"");
        }
    }

    //taken from GhostCat solution
    private static Map<Character, Integer> mapNumOfChars() {

        Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (char charToCount : word.toCharArray()) {

            if (!charMap.containsKey(charToCount)) {
                // unknown char, so we need a counter for it
                charMap.put(charToCount, new Integer(0));
            }
            int currentCounter = charMap.get(charToCount);
            charMap.put(charToCount, ++currentCounter);
        }

        return charMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` test should be within the `for` loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    String strInput  = br.readLine();//read the string 
    int count = 0;
    int h = 0,e = 0,l= 0,o = 0;

    for (int i=0; i< strInput.length();i++){

        if(strInput.charAt(i)=='h'){ h++;}
        else if(strInput.charAt(i)=='l'){l++;}
        else if(strInput.charAt(i)=='e'){e++;}
        else if(strInput.charAt(i)=='o'){o++;}

         //this test should be made with every loop 
        if((h>=1) && (e>=1) && (l>=2) && (o>=1)){
            count++;
            h--;
            e--;
            o--;
            l=l-2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: but actually string is `hello` that he want to match, nd in `hhelllo`, there's no matching string.

Comment: Since `hhelllo` has at lease 1xh & 1xe & 2xll & 1xo it does match.

Comment: it not contain `hello` string..... his code is also wrong, if you take example of `hhelllo`. 2xh 1xe 3xl 1xo, it increase count, but based on character, not based on String

Answer (score 0):

here comes a generic refactored solution to your problem

the main idea is to count how many times we need each character to print our target word, and then see how many times we can find the needed amount inside the provided input.

for example:
  if we want to print AAB and the input is AAABB, we need 2As and 1B to each time we will print, as we only have 3As we can print the As only once, and even if we can print the Bs twice the amount of As will limit us.

---

so with the following code you can call

```
timesCanBePrinted("hello","jhdfjhhelloejhlepoohhello");
```

and you will get the answer 2

```
private static int timesCanBePrinted(String targetWord, String letters) {

        Map<Character, Integer> targetWordMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Character, Integer> lettersWordMap = new HashMap<>();

        //initializing targetWordMap
        //so for hello for example our map will be like this
        //{h:1,e:1,l:2,o:1}
        initializeMapWithCharacterCount(targetWord, targetWordMap);
        initializeMapWithCharacterCount(letters, lettersWordMap);

        int timesCanBePrinted = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        Map<Character, Integer> result = createMapWithNumberOfTimesWeCanUseEachCharacter(targetWordMap, lettersWordMap);

        //now we will look for the character that we can print less times
        //this chacater will determine the number of times we can print the target
        //word
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> resultCountKV : result.entrySet()) {
            if(resultCountKV.getValue()<timesCanBePrinted){
                timesCanBePrinted = resultCountKV.getValue();
            }
        }


        return timesCanBePrinted;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * create the map containing the number of times we can
     * print a given character from the target word, with 
     * the current input
     * 
     * @param targetWordMap
     * @param lettersWordMap
     * @return a map containing containing the number of times we can
     * print a given character 
     */
    private static Map<Character, Integer> createMapWithNumberOfTimesWeCanUseEachCharacter(Map<Character, Integer> targetWordMap,
            Map<Character, Integer> lettersWordMap) {
        Map<Character, Integer> result= new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> neededLetterCount : targetWordMap.entrySet()) {
            int totalTimesWeCanUseThisCharacter = 0;
            if(lettersWordMap.containsKey(neededLetterCount.getKey())){
                totalTimesWeCanUseThisCharacter = lettersWordMap.get(neededLetterCount.getKey())/neededLetterCount.getValue();
            }
            result.put(neededLetterCount.getKey(), totalTimesWeCanUseThisCharacter);
        }

        return result;
    }


        /**
         * initializes targetWordMap
         * so for hello for example our map will be like this
         *  {h:1,e:1,l:2,o:1} 
         * 
         * @param targetWord
         * @param targetWordMap
         */
    private static void initializeMapWithCharacterCount(String targetWord, Map<Character, Integer> targetWordMap) {
        for(int i = 0;i<targetWord.length();i++){
            if(targetWordMap.containsKey(targetWord.charAt(i))){
                targetWordMap.put(targetWord.charAt(i),targetWordMap.get(targetWord.charAt(i))+1);
            }
            else{
                targetWordMap.put(targetWord.charAt(i),1);
            }
        }
    }
```